# Combining two methods into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two methods.

```
def response_code_description(code)
  @response_code_description ||= current_account.one_call_center.response_codes_repository_class.new.to_api_collection
  @response_code_description.find {|k| k['code'] == code}.try(:[], 'description')
end

def ticket_response_code_with_description(ticket_response)
  @ticket_response_code_with_description ||= ticket_response.ticket.one_call_center.response_codes_repository_class.new.to_api_collection
  @ticket_response_code_with_description.find { |k| k['code'] == ticket_response.code }.try(:[], 'description')
 end
```

I think I can combine them.
So.

```
def response_code_with_description(one_call_center, code)
  @ticket_response_code_with_description ||= one_call_center.response_codes_repository_class.new.to_api_collection
  @ticket_response_code_with_description.find { |k| k['code'] == code }.try(:[], 'description')
 end
```

and call this method so

```
 response_code_with_description(current_account.one_call_center, ticket_response.code)
 response_code_with_description(ticket_response.ticket.one_call_center, code)
```

what do you think?

Comment: stackoverflow is specifically for technical problems (bugs, code that isn't doing what it's supposed to, etc). If you're looking for opinions on the best way to organize your code, you should try the [codereview stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: that being said, it looks like you're on the right track. Trying to make a different function for each type of object which contains a `one_call_center` doesn't scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between these two methods seems to be this one part:

```
k['code'] == code
k['code'] == ticket_response.code
```

So in other words you either compare to the argument directly, or the `code` method called on the argument. Address that problem by making the argument adaptive:

```
def to_description(code)
  code = code.code if (code.respond_to?(:code))
  # ... Rest of code presuming `code` is the thing to compare against.
end
```

This eliminates the difference between the two.

I'd strongly encourage you to revisit the names used in your code here s they are unreasonably verbose.